# ServiceStack: Adding Blazor support?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, servicestack, blazor

I have tried adding ServiceStack-references to a client-side Blazor project, but I run into problems after adding ServiceStack.HttpClient via NuGet.

Currently, VS2019 will tell me that:

> Cannot find declaration of exported type 'System.Threading'

and when [ask/look around](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5492), they say that:

> Blazor is built using mono-wasm as the base .NET framework
>   implementation, and in this case I believe it's a missing method in
>   mono-wasm that's the issue.

and

> at present Mono WASM has no support for threading; check the repo
>   https://github.com/lrz/mono-wasm-mono for more info

Am I getting it correctly:

- ServiceStack requires `System.Threading`
- WebAssembly and thus Blazor does not support references to `System.Threading`
- Meaning that ServiceStack cannot be used in a Blazor app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServiceStack's Blazor WASM Template is being maintained by [Sebastian Faltoni](https://github.com/nukedbit) at https://github.com/nukedbit/blazor-wasm-servicestack

Which can be installed with the [x dotnet tool](https://docs.servicestack.net/dotnet-tool):

```
$ dotnet tool install -g x
```

and created with:

```
$ x new nukedbit/blazor-wasm-servicestack ProjectName
```

Or for an installation-free alternative use ServiceStack's online project template builder:
https://servicestack.net/start#community

It includes integration with a Blazor Service Client which can be created at:

```
var client =  BlazorClient.Create("https://localhost:5001")
```

It currently returns a pre-configured `JsonHttpClient` that removes all HttpClient features that Blazor WASM doesn't support. Over time we'll include more features as they're supported in Blazor.

@Issac is incorrect about ServiceStack using Web Sockets, ServiceStack doesn't use Web Sockets in any of its libraries and `BlazorClient` is a Service Client using .NET's HttpClient which Blazor WASM does support.

Comment: Thanks Mythz. So, you are going to look at Blazor support when its officially released, if I read your answer correcty?

Comment: @Ted Right, will be looking into a JSON Service Client for Blazor after it’s officially released.

Comment: Mythz has updated the answer on sept 11 2021, so now there is some support for Blazor client it seems.

Answer (score 1):

@Ted,

Blazor does not run in a multi-thread environment. Blazor (mono-wasm) runs in the same sandbox of JavaScript, in the same UI thread. No multi-threading, no concurrent or parallel programming. As I've said before, I've never heard of ServiceStack, but I guess that ServiceStack.HttpClient cannot be used in Blazor client side, as "Blazor HttpClient" is based on HttpMessageHandler, and it is adapted to work as an Ajax agent; that is, HttpClient communicate with the Back End via the JavaScript Fetch Web API, whereas ServiceStack, I believe, perform the traditional http client calls, employing Web Sockets, which is not supported in Blazor (mono-wasm). In Asp.Net Core 5.0 it is expected that Blazor client side would support Web Sockets, after mono would be replaced.

No, the ServiceStack cannot be used in a Blazor app

Hope this helps...